# Are inbuilt layouts in Android Styleable?

Tags: java, android

Is possible to apply styling to Android inbuilt layouts such as R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice?

Comment: What do you mean by 'apply styling'? Do you mean applying a Theme? Or changing attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?  The below XML makes any listView's in the app have a grey background (shamelessly taken from http://http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/)

Styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style
    name="MyTheme"
    parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item
      name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item
      name="android:colorBackground">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item
      name="android:panelColorBackground">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item
      name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
  </style>
  <style
    name="MyListView"
    parent="android:Widget.ListView.White">
    <item
      name="android:background">@color/light_grey</item>
  </style>
  <style
    name="MyDefaultTextAppearance"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item
      name="android:textSize">14dip</item>
    <item
      name="android:textColor">#333</item>
    <item
      name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```